# If $G=\langle{a}\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order 4, what would the permutations in $S_4$ that would form a subgroup of $S_4 \cong G$ be?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know Cayley's Theorem states that every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group acting on $G$. The proof of his theorem seems to hint at finding the 4 permutations

Comment: Consider the cyclic group $\langle(1234)\rangle$.

Comment: 2 questions; For the group you described ($\langle(1234)\rangle$), what is the generator element? And would the permutations simply be $(1)(2)(3)(4)...$?

Comment: The generator is $(1234)$. The permutations are $(1234), (13)(24), (1432)$ and the identity.

Comment: @RoyM. The permutations $(1),(2),(3),(4)$ are all the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator is the number in the $\langle{ }\rangle$.  THus the generator I'm describing above is the element $(1234)$.  Why?

$$(1234)^1=(1234)$$
$$(1234)^2=(1234)(1234)=(13)(24)$$
$$(1234)^3=(13)(24)(1234)=(1432)$$
$$(1234)^4=(1432)(1234)=(1)$$

As Vladhagen mentioned in his answer, this is a subgroup of order 4.

Answer (score 6):

Isn't this just *any* 4-cycle? The 4-cycles, and the 4-cycles only, form cyclic groups of order 4 in $S_4$. Am I misunderstanding the question?